# Why does my geoserver colour things differently depending on the zoom?

Tags: leaflet, geoserver

I have some layers in Geoserver that come from a database. In it I load thousands of points that I represent graphically and paint in green or pink depending on whether they are active or not.

The problem is that depending on the zoom level the colors change (they look pink when they should be green).

Where the blue dots are, the circles should be green.

```
var zonesT = L.tileLayer.wms("https://geoserver.abcd.com/geoserver/abcd/wms", {
            layers: 'city:points',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: "true",
            attribution: "city"
    });
```

Zoom 1: OK
[image]

Zoom 2: Incorrect, the center points are painted pink

[image]

Zoom 3: OK

[image]

Any suggestion of the error? Thanks

Comment: we'd need your data and sld at least to start debugging this

Comment: And this is missing whether the data coming out of geoserver and into leaflet is WMS images, WFS features, or something else.

Comment: A call to a WMS service